# Multi SSL certificate on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, rhel6, lets-encrypt, multiple-instances

I am trying to install two certificates generated from Letsencrypt using gethttpsforfree.com. I have followed the steps as mentioned for each domain and was able to generate the certificates too. After copying the crt and pem file for each domain and configuring virtual host entries with the separate certificates in ssl.conf I am unable to start the webserver. If I am commenting out the virtualhost entry for second application, I am able to start apache. On checking the ssl error log for second application it says

```
 
[error] Unable to configure RSA server private key

[error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

Please help

Comment: You will need to show your Apache configuration. But you probably mixed your 2 private keys and 2 public certs in some way in the configuration hence the error.

Comment: You are right Patrick.. I have mixed the keys and certificates. Once again I did the certificate generation for the second site and pointed the ssl certs and keys correctly and it worked. Infact I saved the file  domain.key by same name and the mixup happened there. Anyways thanks for the response.